# How is Unity's [Command] supposed to behave?

Tags: unity, unity-networking

Here's a very simple class/call hierarchy:

```
public class NetworkPlayer : NetworkBehaviour {
    public static NetworkPlayer localPlayer {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdTurnDone() {
        Debug.Log("Turn done! isServer "+isServer+" isClient "+isClient+" isLocalPlr "+isLocalPlayer);
    }
}

public class SomeMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        NetworkPlayer.localPlayer.CmdTurnDone(); 
    }
}
```

When `Update()` gets executed on the **host**, it outputs as expected:

> Turn done! isServer True isClient True isLocalPlr True

Now, when `Update()` is executed on the **remote client** it outputs the following at the **remote client's log only**. However, the message does not appear at the **server's** logs:

> Turn done! isServer False isClient True isLocalPlr True

What puzzles me is why the message appears at the **remote client's** log only.

If I'm not mistaken, calling `CmdTurnDone()` at the **remote client** should execute it on the **server**. But why does the log message appear at the **remote client's** log instead of on the **server's** logs - where it is executed? Is it valid to call `CmdTurnDone()` from a `MonoBehaviour`?
Do you have any ideas why it's behaving like this? Is this the intended behavior? Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, both your server and your client will do it separately, then the server will correct the client if there are any discrepancies between the two, but I can't really offer expert opinion.

Comment: Oddly enough, no message shows up at the server's log as long as Update() is called on the remote client. It seems like it's executed on the remote client only.

Comment: Unity's UNet stuff operates on magic.